# Filter Street View by Image Capture Date

Tags: bing-maps, google-street-view, google-streetview-publish, google-street-view-static-api

Is it possible to filter the Google street view or Bing Streetside view by Capture Date? Ideally I would be able to give a date interval and only see those streets highligted in blue that were captured during the requested interval? Even if the solution is not straight forward, I can implement it so long as it is scaleable.

Reviewed google documentation but can't find a way to implement this functionality. The closest I found is that there is a similar functionality in google earth but it is only for satelite view rather than street view

Comment: As you have found out. There's no such feature in the Google Maps API for it. Static Streetview only returns the date of the capture but requesting using such parameters is not supported. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata

Answer (score 0):

It's possible generate a list of the Street Views (blue lines) you published using the List function of the Street View Publish API. The list will include the capture date for each Street View (photosequence). You could then easily filter the list using the desired date range. You would need to add the map display yourself.

Comment: would you share more details , exmples , links to how to achieve this?

Comment: The VIEWS tool in my UL2GSV suite uses the List function and creates a .csv file containing a line for each Street View. You can join the Google Group at the link below for access to it.



https://groups.google.com/g/ul2gsv

Comment: thanks, I've joined. What particular discusstion there should I choose ?

Comment: There is no discussion to join. Joining the Google Group provides access to the software I mentioned.